# Chromedriver: Support multiple versions in PyInstalled exe

Tags: python, windows-installer, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I want to distribute my Chrome automation tool to some users, but unfortunately it seems every Chromedriver vesion only supports one Chrome version which is really bad.

For Firefox the geckodriver support multiple versions at once. But the requirement for this deployed tool is to use Chrome.

So I'm wondering what would be the best way to support not only the latest Chrome version, but also older versions and also the beta channel releases without bloating the .exe file to much.

And the only solution I can see is to fetch the installed Chrome version and download the appropriate Chromedriver on the fly, is it?

Any other ideas?
Is there any way to check the installed Chrome version without accessing the Registry because the latter requires admin rights?

Thanks!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/505531/what-version-of-google-chrome-do-i-have

Comment: Unfortunately Im on windows